# How can I prove this claim about splitting of prime ideals in real cyclotomic fields?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, cyclotomic-fields

Let $L_k = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k} + \zeta_{2^k}^{-1})$ be the maximal real subfield of the cyclotomic field of conductor $2^k, k \ge 2$ and $f_k(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{2^k} + \zeta_{2^k}^{-1}$.

Define $L = L_{k+1}, K = L_{k}$ so $L/K$ has degree 2. Assume a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ above $p$ splits in $\mathcal{O}_L$ as $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{p}_1 \mathfrak{p}_2$. Then I suspect that $p\mathcal{O}_L$ totally splits (in which case $p\mathcal{O}_K$ totally splits as well). How can I prove this?

I believe this is equivalent to showing that if $f_{k+1}(x)$ has 2 roots over $\mathbb{F}_p$ then it factors completely over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I'm not sure how that can be shown. Are there any general approaches to take here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $\text{Gal}(L_k/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic and look at the fixed field of the decomposition group.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? If $p\mathcal{O}_K$ totally splits then I think we should have trivial decomposition group $D_\mathfrak{p}$ with fixed field = $K$, but I don't see how to use this.

Comment: Look at the decomposition group of the rational prime $p$ in $\text{Gal}(L_k/\mathbb{Q})$ not in $\text{Gal}(L_k/L_{k - 1})$. If the fixed field of the decomposition group is $E$, then there is no more splitting in the extension $L_k/E$. But we know that there is splitting in $L_k/L_{k - 1}$ by assumption, hence $E = L_k$ and the decomposition group is trivial, so $p$ splits completely.

Comment: I see now, thanks!